# Report sites where owners post documents with my full name

Tags: privacy

Where can I go to report websites that have published my full name? There are some blogs and sites, but just a few hosts.

These sites are posting content with my **fullname**, and I would like to report it to Google (regarding **blogspot**), and also to the correct institution (regarding a website, not really the site owner, such as scribd.com).

I asked the owner of these sites and they just don't remove my name.

Is there a fast way to report these pages to some institutions, telling they are publishing my name without my permission?

Comment: Interesting question... Definitely not for Super User. Anyway, I don't think you can get someone to remove your name from the web unless it is used to defame you or do something similar. I can go and write your name on my fence and doubt you'll be able to get someone to make me remove it. The Web has the same situation. Only if you prove they are harming your reputation in some way then you might get somewhere. Better get a lawyer's opinion here.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least get set up [Google Alert](http://www.google.com/alerts)s to search for your full name, one for last name + first name, one for first name + last name. But I am afraid the reporting has to be done manually.

Comment: This doesn't help the question at hand. This is simply to help notify him of author things that may be his that are newly added to the Google search. He wants to remove these infringing pieces from Google and from the site.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [filing a complaint with the Federal Trade Commission](https://www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov/) but I wouldn't expect to see swift action, even if it's actionable by them.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already complained to the website owner, I think the best next step is to talk to the hosting company. What you want to do is look at the ToS and find as many infringements as possible and then report it. Web hosting companies are generally very attentive and swift with their actions. However, the result may be that the website gets taken down completely.

If you are so concerned about your document, have you put a copyright notice on it? This will definitely help your case.